# Проблема в асинхронном callback - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback, асинхронность, userjs

Пишу простенький скрипт который собирает картинки на странице, конвертит их в base64 и передает на сервер

примерно с таким кодом

```
function convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, callback, outputFormat){
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
    canvas = null; 
  };
  img.src = url;
}

var d = $("td[style='width: 315px;']");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var arr =[];
  var uri = d[i].innerHTML.match(/src=\"(.+?)\"><\/strong>/)[1].replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
  var cod = d[i].innerHTML.match(/\(<strong>(\d+?)<\/strong>\)/)[1];
  var id = uri.match(/id=(\d+?)&/)[1];
  convertToDataURLviaCanvas('http://www.yyy.yy'+ uri, function(base64Img){
    console.log(base64Img); // ok
    arr.push('http://xxx.xx/base.php?base='+ base64Img.replace(/\+/g,"_") +'|'+ id +'_'+ i +'_'+ cod +''); // i = 3 - wtf??
    console.log(arr);
  });
  console.log(arr); //array empty - wtf???
  console.log(i); // ok
}
```

не могу понять почему когда обращаюсь к калбек функции у меня как то не естественно себя ведет инкримент, не могу сделать массив для дальнейшей обработки

Comment: var arr =[]; это конечно же перед циклом, опечатался при копировании сюда

Comment: вы можете отредактировать свой вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> не естественно себя ведет инкримент

Конечно, коллбек работает асинхронно, и инкремент уже "не тот".
Просто передайте инкремент в коллбек и верните его (и не забывайте про отступы *читать Ваш вопрос сложно*):

```
function convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, data, callback, outputFormat){
   var img = new Image();
   img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
   img.onload = function(){
      var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var dataURL;
      canvas.height = this.height;
      canvas.width = this.width;
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
      callback(dataURL, data);
      canvas = null; 
  };
  img.src = url;
}
var d = $("td[style='width: 315px;']");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var arr =[];
    var uri = d[i].innerHTML.match(/src=\"(.+?)\"><\/strong>/)[1].replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
    var cod = d[i].innerHTML.match(/\(<strong>(\d+?)<\/strong>\)/)[1];
    var id = uri.match(/id=(\d+?)&/)[1];
    convertToDataURLviaCanvas('http://www.yyy.yy'+ uri, {i:i, cod:cod, id:id}, function(base64Img, data){
        i = data.i
        id = data.id
        cod = data.cod
        console.log(base64Img); // ok
        arr.push('http://xxx.xx/base.php?base='+ base64Img.replace(/\+/g,"_") +'|'+ id +'_'+ i +'_'+ cod +''); // i = 3 - wtf??
        console.log(arr); // Тут arr имеет ожидаемое значение
    });
    console.log(arr); //array empty - wtf??? - Коллбек еще не отработал
    console.log(i); // ok
}
```

Скорее всего `cod` и `id` Вы тоже захотите передать в коллбек - обновил ответ

Comment: стоило сделать внутри колбэка локальные _i_ и т.д. чтобы не путать со счетчиком цикла